# ng2-toastr not working in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-toastr

I am trying to use ng2-toastr in my angular 2 app. I have followed all the instructions but the toastr fails to show up without any console error. I have also read somewhere that ng-toastr no longer works with angular 2 but have not found any valid documentation on that. 
I have searched for similar questions but have not found any suitable answer to my problem. any help would be appreciated.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import{ ToastModule} from 'ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-
browser/animations';
import "hammerjs"

import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';

import { MODULE_ROUTES, MODULE_COMPONENTS } from './app.router'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MODULE_COMPONENTS
],
imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   FormsModule,
   HttpModule,
   RouterModule.forRoot(MODULE_ROUTES),
   BrowserAnimationsModule,
   CoreModule,
   ToastModule.forRoot()
],
providers: [ ],
bootstrap: [MODULE_COMPONENTS]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastsManager } from 'ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr';

@Component({
  selector: 'wow-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor( public toastr: ToastsManager, private vRef: ViewContainerRef) 
  {
    this.toastr.setRootViewContainerRef(vRef);
    console.log(this.toastr);
  }

}
```

This is how I am calling toastr method in one of my components:

```
 login() {
   this.user_service.login(this.user).then((response) => {
     console.log(response)
     this.toastrManager.success('Successfully Logged in.')
   }
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^4.1.3",
"@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
"angular2-image-upload": "^0.6.1",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"jquery": "^3.2.1",
"ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
"rxjs": "^5.1.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular/cli": "1.0.3",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
  "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38" 
}
```

I have also added `"../node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.css"` in my angular-cli.json.
this is [console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdDuQ.png)

Comment: have you added `node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.js` file in angular-cli.json file ?

Comment: I guess that's not required when working with webpack/angular-cli

Comment: but you have to add `js` file for external library you used in your project.

Comment: No I don't. its mentioned in their documentation. 
'NOTE: If you are using angular-cli you do not need to include 'node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.js', since adding 'import {ToastModule} from 'ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr';' to your module file (below) will allow it to be autoloaded."

Comment: oh okay , sorry i did't read this yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**UPDATE**]

I finally managed to solve the problem, thought to share it with all those who are stuck in the same issue. Please change the following code

```
import { ToastsManager } from 'ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr';
```

to

```
import { ToastsManager } from 'ng2-toastr';
```

since, the ToastsManager is exported from the parent directory and not from the subdirectory (atleast, in the versions of dependencies I am using).

Comment: can you share with me your setup of the toastr?

Answer (score 5):

In your angular-cli.json file, add this line in a styles property

```
../node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.css
```

Answer (score 1):

- i am playing with error with 1hrs , finally i find the following
  solution:

  1. first you need to copy the "ng2-toastr.min.css" from
     nodemodules-->ng2toaster folder
  2. put this file in yours assests ,and add link in yours base
     "index.html" file

> ```
>   <link href="assets/css/ng2-toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
> ```